# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'support_functions'

Tags: python, module

I am trying to import following in jupyter notebook.

How do I import module Support_funcions?

```
from support_functions import calculate_accuracy, plot_confusion_matrix

Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d809bed20d2c> in <module>
     20 
     21 # Support functions import
---> 22 from support_functions import calculate_accuracy, plot_confusion_matrix

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'support_functions'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure setup is correct for Python.  Add the file for support_functions (support_functions.py question) to the systems python._pth file.